# problem with route `/item/gorod_(byaz_220_sm)_sinego_tsveta_1100.037_1` flashing 404 before finally rendering page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router, react-router-dom

After updating React from 15.3 to 16.3 we are faced with a problem with react-router.
I'm currently experiencing a problem with my **'/item/gorod_(byaz_220_sm)_sinego_tsveta_1100.037_1'** routes where react flashes the **404 page** before successfully rendering my component.I road a lot of article of that problem but not found the information which will solve my problem.

Stages of problem:

1. First I clicked to my component [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyM3w.png)

Code of my component:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj9ed.png)

2. After clicking handelCardCLick triggers the function:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObXNR.png)

In the variable link located the string of url

const link = /item/gorod_(byaz_220_sm)_sinego_tsveta_1100.037_1

3. After clicking I routered to link. If I try to click the button f5(for refreshing the page) I see the page 404

**Page no fount 404**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXqg1.png)

4. After that load a component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIjU2.png)

Comment: Please add code directly instead of posting screenshots of it. It'll help others to debug your code and answer quickly.

Comment: What version of react-router-dom are you using? Why do you include a `to` prop with the link then also try to manage navigation manually via the `onClick` handler?